# chef running resource only when a package is present

Tags: chef-infra

I want to unzip one file in chef recipe but I want to ensure that unzip package is install on that machine before I unzip it. How to do it in chef ?

I tried below recipe but on machine where unzip package is install it simply don't execute it.

```
bash 'extract' do
    cwd '/home/norun/'
    code <<-EOH
        unzip wso2.zip
        EOH
    only_if { ::File.exists?('/home/norun/wso2.zip') }
    not_if { ::File.exists?('/home/norun/wso2as-5.2.1') }
end

apt_package 'unzip' do
    action :install
    notifies :run , 'bash[extract]', :immediately
end
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order, as order matters in chef:

```rb
package 'unzip' do
    action :install
    # notifies :run , 'bash[extract]', :immediately
end
```

This will make sure that the `unzip` utility is installed. Btw you can use the `package` resource, as this makes your code more portable. Chef will automatically select the right provider. Further, I suggest to remove the notification from `package[unzip]`, as the unzip process will not be triggered, if `unzip` was already installed.

```rb
bash 'extract_wso2' do
    cwd '/home/norun/'
    code 'unzip wso2.zip'
    only_if { ::File.exists?('/home/norun/wso2.zip') }
    not_if { ::File.exists?('/home/norun/wso2as-5.2.1') }
end
```

You don't need to notify the `bash[extract_wso2]` resource, as it is guarded by the `not_if`.

Instead of manually unzipping, you might also want to use the [ark](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ark) cookbook.